# How to put comma separated array of json into span tags coming from ngFor in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have simple array of object.I am using those into loop ngFor. I can able to render. But the problem is json contains Treatment":"OPD,MEDICINES". So I need to iterate those comma separated value into span and put border.Here is the code below

### home.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="mb-3 text-right">
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" autocomplete="off" class="col-md-3 searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table table-bordered expensetable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Treatment</th>
        <th>Expenses</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngIf="( getListData | filter:searchText) as result">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of result">
        <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Treatment}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Expenses}}</td>
      </tr>
     <tr *ngIf="result.length === 0">
        <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Data Found</td>      
      </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonserviceService } from './../utilities/services/commonservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  getListData: any;
  constructor(private commonserviceService: CommonserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getHeroes();
  }
getHeroes(){
   this.commonserviceService.getData().subscribe(getListData =>{
          this.getListData = getListData;
          console.log(this.getListData);
      },
      (error) => {
      alert('No data');
      }
  );
}
}
```

### commonservice.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonserviceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getData(){
      let url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";
      return this.http.get(url)
     .map(
     (res) =>{
    let resData = /*res;*/ [{"Date":"8/02/2020","Expenses":750,"Treatment":"OPD,MEDICINES"},{"Date":"15/02/2020","Expenses":2565,"Treatment":"OPD,MEDICINES,ULTRASOUND SCAN"}]
    console.log(resData);
    return  resData;

     }
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. What does your json look like? 2. How should the output look like? 3. Could you include a stackblitz?

Comment: Please find the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yp9ngz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html   , I have added expected output for reference

Comment: @carreankush have a look in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

1) Create a function in ts file. This function will split your treatment string by comma. Use javascript native function split for this. This will return you an array. Loop through this array and create desired html.

2) Use `[innerHtml]` to assign value in td of table

.ts file

```
getTreatment(data) {
    let str = ''
    let arr = data.split(',');
    if (arr.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str += '<p>' + arr[i] + '</p>'
      }
    }
    return str
  }
```

.html

```
<table class="table" border="1px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Treatment</th>
        <th>Expenses</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ng-container>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of resData">
        <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
        <td [innerHtml]="getTreatment(item.Treatment)"></td>
        <td>{{item.Expenses}}</td>
      </tr>

      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwd3us

**Note :** : It may also done using pipe as well. You can try it using pipe